# Unable to run core_email_queue_send_all task?

Tags: magento-1.9

i tried to run the core_email_queue_send_all task from AOE scheduler and I got the error. Please see screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can get this error if there is another instance of the same task still running / was aborted without being terminated properly. Check `System > Scheduler > List View` and filter by the task name. Delete any old entries of this task and try again.

If it still doesn't work please [debug the store](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store/429#429) and edit your question with more information.